# EPPlus: CSV to Excel - Result all in one line

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, epplus

I am experiencing a weird problem, when exporting an excel file on Linux using [EPPlus](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus) version `4.5.3.3`.

The problem is, that when generating CSV content and using that content to generate the excel file, the whole result ends up in the first row of the excel-sheet (using Libre-Office on Ubuntu). This does only happen on Linux (Ubuntu and Debian tested), but not on Windows. Another weird thing is, when I don't use CSV content to generate the excel file, but a collection, it does work with no problems. Sadly, that way, there is no way to use custom headers.

Code for generating the CSV:

```cs
private static string GenerateCsv()
{
    var header = $"{nameof(Menu.Main)}{Delimiter}{nameof(Menu.Desert)}";
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.AppendLine(header);

    foreach (var menu in Menus)
    {
        var row = $"{menu.Main}{Delimiter}{menu.Desert}";
        builder.AppendLine(row);
    }

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Code for generating the excel file:

```cs
var csv = GenerateCsv();

using var pck = new ExcelPackage();

var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");

var format = new ExcelTextFormat
{
    DataTypes = new[]
    {
        eDataTypes.String, eDataTypes.String
    },
    Delimiter = Delimiter.First(),
    Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(),
};

using var range = ws.Cells[1, 1];

range.LoadFromText(csv, format);

var bytes = pck.GetAsByteArray();

return this.File(bytes, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "menus.xlsx", true);
```

The full sample can be cloned from this [github-repository](https://github.com/alsami/EppPlus.CsvToExcel.LinuxProblem). If you are executing it on windows, you will see that it works just fine.

- To export the CSV -> http://localhost:5000/api/v1/menus/csv (result is fine on windows and linux)
- To export the excel file using the CSV -> http://localhost:5000/api/v1/menus/csv-to-excel (result is fine on windows but not on linux)
- To export the excel file using a collection -> http://localhost:5000/api/v1/menus/list-to-excel (result is fine on windows and linux)

I really tried a lot of things and also tried changing the delimiter from `;` to `,`, introduced a text-qualifier and what not, but can't seem to make it work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `StringBuilder.AppendLine` in `CreateCsv` terminates each line
with the default line terminator of the OS which is on:

- Windows `\r\n`
- Unix `\n`

EPPlus doesn't respect the default line terminator of the OS and uses `\r\n` as a default value.
That's why it works on Windows.

So you can set the `ExcelTextFormat.EOL` property to `Environment.NewLine` to use the default line terminator of the OS.

```
var format = new ExcelTextFormat
{
    DataTypes = new[]
    {
        eDataTypes.String, eDataTypes.String
    },
    Delimiter = Delimiter.First(),
    Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(),
    EOL = Environment.NewLine
};
```